# Python x509 get_serial_number() return incorrect value

Tags: python, x509, m2crypto

I'm trying to get the serial number of a x509 with M2cryto the problem is that returns me different values ​​to openssl.

from python

```
>>> from M2Crypto import X509
>>> cer = X509.load_cert(cerPath, X509.FORMAT_DER)
>>> cer.get_serial_number()
286524172099382162235533054529634765881071645240L
```

from openssl

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in cer.cer -serial -noout
serial=3230303031303030303030323030303031343238
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a matter of the number format, the number with the decimal presentation

```
286524172099382162235533054529634765881071645240
```

has this hexadecimal presentation

```
3230303031303030303030323030303031343238
```

it's merely a matter of base change.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. I used it to change number format

```
>>> '{0:x}'.format(int(cer.get_serial_number()))
3230303031303030303030323030303031343238
```